# Configuring Azure Website "Always On" Mode using Management API

Tags: azure, azure-web-app-service, azure-sdk-.net

It is possible to set an Azure Website to "Always On" using the Azure Portal.

I'm trying to achieve the same using the Azure SDK

```
var config = new WebSiteUpdateConfigurationParameters
{
    WebSocketsEnabled = true,
    AppSettings = appSettings,
    ConnectionStrings = connectionStrings,
    Use32BitWorkerProcess = false,
    ????
};

await client.WebSites.UpdateConfigurationAsync(webSpaceName, sitename, config);
```

Is there any workaround for this or am I missing something?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It does not look like AlwaysOn property has been added to the Azure SDK yet. We will add it in the upcoming SDK releases.

Unfortunately at the moment the only workaround is to call the Azure Web Sites API directly - http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/azure/dn166985.aspx (the docs are a bit out of date as they do not mention AlwaysOn, but the API will accept it).